# How to get data from dataset on basis of condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have filled dataset with this data now I want to pick particular column from it but based on condition, I don't want to connect database each time just picking from dataset would be great.
So how can I apply condition on dataset like where clause etc?

Dataset [image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        DataSet dss = CalendarSpotting();
        Session["Calendar"] = dss;
    }
}

protected void Calndar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["Calendar"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i like to do is:

> DataTable theTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

Or:

> DataTable theTable = dataSet.Tables["YourTableName"];

Which makes it much easier to loop through columns and rows in my
experience.Like this:

```
if(theTable.Rows[0]["YourColumnName"].toString() == "Itsmee")
{
 // do this, do that

}
```